# How to select which battery the laptop should use via command line or configuration file?

Tags: battery

My laptop has two batteries: battery 0 and battery 1.  I'd like to be able to choose which
battery is being used via some command line program or maybe changing some
configuration file in the OS.

### context

Battery 0 is only used after battery 1 has been drained out. The problem with
this is that -- besides overwheelming battery 1 while battery 0 does nothing --
recently battery 1 has started disappearing from the system when it gets to low
power. It literally disappears: it does not show up using the command `acpi`
and the directory `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` is removed.

So, basically the OS cannot detect the battery 1 hardware. A very unfortunate
result of it is that even if I plug on the laptop the battery 1 won't get
charged! Sometimes even after rebooting the laptop it won't detect battery 1.
Later on, the battery 1 randomly shows up and I'm able to charge it.

BTW, the batteries are both internal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the kernel documentation you can use battery charge control.
Set your first battery to start charging when below 99% and your second to start charging at 0%.

Example usage:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/g8kpee/psa_kernel_54_added_the_ability_to_set_a_battery/

Kernel doc:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.html?highlight=charge_control_start_threshold#battery-charge-control

Comment: sorry, but I still didn't get how I'd force the PC to use one of the batteries and not use the other

Comment: you can try keeping one of your batteries always discharged by setting charge_control_end_threshold to 1